# Bogus faker how to set a list of string array

Tags: c#, string, list, faker, bogus

I would like to ask your help to use Bogus Faker.

I have this

```
private readonly Faker _faker;

_faker = new Faker("fr");

List<string> _randomString = (List<string>)_faker.Make(3, () => _faker.Random.Word()); // OK

List<string[]> _randomStrinArray = (List<string[]>)_faker.Make(3, () => _faker.Random.Word()); // KO
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you found your solution. That's great by the way!

Here are some other alternatives if you're intrested:

```cs
var faker = new Faker();

List<string> randomStrings = Enumerable.Range(1,7)
                       .Select(_ => faker.Random.Word())
                       .ToList();
randomStrings.Dump();
```

[image: output]

```cs
List<string[]> randomStringArray = Enumerable.Range(1,7)
      .Select(_ => faker.Random.WordsArray(1,4))
      .ToList();

randomStringArray.Dump();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brian for the reply.

Answer (score 4):

Hello I found the solution

```
List<string[]> _randomStrinArray = (List<string[]>) _faker.Make(3, () => _faker.Random.WordsArray(1,4));
```